# Google charts script return error on feed Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string

Tags: php, charts

The following script using Google charts returns a error

**Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string**

Basically booking are made daily and are Active when a booking has been seen it will be given different attribute. It should count the booking1_date and return a number for that date and display but it doesn't.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
 google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
 function drawChart() {
 var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([

 ['booking1_date', 'bookings'],
 <?php 
 $query = "SELECT count(status) As count, booking1_date FROM crm  where status = 'Active' GROUP BY booking1_date ORDER BY 
     CASE
          WHEN booking1_date = 'Sunday' THEN 1
          WHEN booking1_date = 'Monday' THEN 2
          WHEN booking1_date = 'Tuesday' THEN 3
          WHEN booking1_date = 'Wednesday' THEN 4
          WHEN booking1_date = 'Thursday' THEN 5
          WHEN booking1_date = 'Friday' THEN 6
          WHEN booking1_date = 'Saturday' THEN 7
     END ASC";

 $exec = mysqli_query($con,$query);
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($exec)){

 echo "['".$row['booking1_date']."',".$row['count']."],";

 }
 ?>
 ]);

 var options = {
   title: 'Bookings this week'
 };

 var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("columnchart"));
   chart.draw(data, options);
 }

 </script>
```

Comment: wow i pleased it not just me that cant work this out